# How can I convert this SQL query to Laravel 5.4?

Tags: laravel

select cu.storage_location,max(current_6kg)opbal6kg,max(current_13kg)opbal13kg, max(current_burner)opbalBurners,max(current_grill)opbalGrills, max(current_50kg)opbal50kg,max(Loaded6KG)in_6kg,max(Loaded13KG)in_13kg,max(Loaded50KG)in_50kg, max(burners)in_burners,max(grills)in_grills ,sum(Unsold6KG)Unsold6KG,sum(Unsold13KG)Unsold13KG,sum(Unsold50KG)Unsold50KG, sum(out_6kg)out_6kg,sum(out_13kg)out_13kg,sum(out_50kg)out_50kg, sum(out_burners)out_burners,sum(out_grills)out_grills from tbl_current_stocks_filled cu left outer join( select * from tblStockTransfer where cast(DateTransferred as date)= cast(getdate() as date)) t on t.destination =cu.storage_location left outer join ( select assignedLocation, sum (op_bal_6KG+Loaded6KG)out_6kg,sum(op_bal_13KG+Loaded13KG)out_13kg, sum(op_bal_50KG+Loaded50KG)out_50kg ,sum(op_bal_grills+Grills)out_grills, sum(op_bal_burners+Burners)out_burners from tblTruckLoading l inner join tblUsers u on l.UserID=u.UserID where cast(l.DateLoaded as date)= cast(getdate() as date) group by assignedLocation ) y on y.assignedLocation=cu.storage_location left outer join ( select Unsold6KG,Unsold13KG,Unsold50KG,UnsoldBurners,UnsoldGrills, assignedLocation from tblTruckUnLoading l left outer join tblUsers u on u.UserID=l.UserID where cast(l.DateOffLoaded as date)= cast(getdate() as date) )x on x.assignedLocation=cu.storage_location
group by cu.storage_location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `DB::raw` method found in the documentation here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

```
$results = DB::select( DB::raw("select cu.storage_location,max(current_6kg)opbal6kg,max(current_13kg)opbal13kg, max(current_burner)opbalBurners,max(current_grill)opbalGrills, max(current_50kg)opbal50kg,max(Loaded6KG)in_6kg,max(Loaded13KG)in_13kg,max(Loaded50KG)in_50kg, max(burners)in_burners,max(grills)in_grills ,sum(Unsold6KG)Unsold6KG,sum(Unsold13KG)Unsold13KG,sum(Unsold50KG)Unsold50KG, sum(out_6kg)out_6kg,sum(out_13kg)out_13kg,sum(out_50kg)out_50kg, sum(out_burners)out_burners,sum(out_grills)out_grills from tbl_current_stocks_filled cu left outer join( select * from tblStockTransfer where cast(DateTransferred as date)= cast(getdate() as date)) t on t.destination =cu.storage_location left outer join ( select assignedLocation, sum (op_bal_6KG+Loaded6KG)out_6kg,sum(op_bal_13KG+Loaded13KG)out_13kg, sum(op_bal_50KG+Loaded50KG)out_50kg ,sum(op_bal_grills+Grills)out_grills, sum(op_bal_burners+Burners)out_burners from tblTruckLoading l inner join tblUsers u on l.UserID=u.UserID where cast(l.DateLoaded as date)= cast(getdate() as date) group by assignedLocation ) y on y.assignedLocation=cu.storage_location left outer join ( select Unsold6KG,Unsold13KG,Unsold50KG,UnsoldBurners,UnsoldGrills, assignedLocation from tblTruckUnLoading l left outer join tblUsers u on u.UserID=l.UserID where cast(l.DateOffLoaded as date)= cast(getdate() as date) )x on x.assignedLocation=cu.storage_location group by cu.storage_location") );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot aceraven77  ,the query you gave me is working

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please mark my answer as best answer :)

Comment: How can i add  a where clause in laravel at the end of the query

Comment: Like adding  ->where('tblStockTransfer.DateTimeStamp', '>=', $constraints['from'])
        ->where('tblStockTransfer.DateTimeStamp', '<=', $constraints['to'])
        ->orderBy('tblStockTransfer.DateTimeStamp', 'DESC')
  ->paginate();